# command aws not found in ubuntu 19.10 after pip install awscli

Tags: python, 19.10, amazon-ec2

I am trying to pro grammatically connect to an aws instance.
So on my Ubuntu 19.10 I did

```
python -m install -u pip
/usr/bin/python: No module named install
```

[instructions](https://cloudranger.com/how-to-configure-the-aws-cli-and-launch-an-ec2-instance/) 
then I did

```
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$ pip install awscli
Collecting awscli
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/d8/e466a8ab05244ea2688f76b0f28f02cf21b0821197ccabba5363e5363521/awscli-1.18.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 75kB/s 
Collecting s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/79/e6afb3d8b0b4e96cefbdc690f741d7dd24547ff1f94240c997a26fa908d3/s3transfer-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (69kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 905kB/s 
Collecting botocore==1.15.13 (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/ca/cd7cac60b830ec3e6b1f9ff924421a11e14a4c1cb1960b22c20e9a7c62e6/botocore-1.15.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.9MB 13kB/s 
Collecting docutils<0.16,>=0.10 (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/dc/bf2b15d1fa15a6f7a9e77a61b74ecbbae7258558fcda8ffc9a6638a6b327/docutils-0.15.2-py2-none-any.whl (548kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 590kB/s 
Collecting PyYAML<5.4,>=3.10; python_version != "3.4" (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/d9/ea9816aea31beeadccd03f1f8b625ecf8f645bd66744484d162d84803ce5/PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz (268kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/ae/baedc9cb175552e95f3395c43055a6a5e125ae4d48a1d7a924baca83e92e/rsa-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting colorama<0.4.4,>=0.2.5; python_version != "3.4" (from awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/dc/45cdef1b4d119eb96316b3117e6d5708a08029992b2fee2c143c7a0a5cc5/colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.7" (from s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0->awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/a6/f46ae3f1da0cd4361c344888f59ec2f5785e69c872e175a748ef6071cdb5/futures-3.3.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.15.13->awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/43/1e939e1fcd87b827fe192d0c9fc25b48c5b3368902bfb913de7754b0dc03/jmespath-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.15.13->awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version != "3.4" (from botocore==1.15.13->awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/74/6e4f91745020f967d09332bb2b8b9b10090957334692eb88ea4afe91b77f/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.6MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.15.13->awscli) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyYAML
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyYAML ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/debian/.cache/pip/wheels/e4/76/4d/a95b8dd7b452b69e8ed4f68b69e1b55e12c9c9624dd962b191
Successfully built PyYAML
Installing collected packages: futures, jmespath, python-dateutil, urllib3, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, PyYAML, pyasn1, rsa, colorama, awscli
  The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-decrypt-bigfile, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-encrypt-bigfile, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/debian/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Now I do check if awscli has been installed I get following

`$aws --version` here is the output

```
Command 'aws' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install aws-cli  # version 1.16.266, or
sudo apt  install awscli   # version 1.16.218-1

See 'snap info aws-cli' for additional versions.
```

So why did installing awscli from python or pip failed. What mistake I did here?

**update 1**
now I did `apt-get install python3-pip` as per suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023599/usr-local-bin-python-no-module-named-pip

```
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$ pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

so how to use pip3 for installing awscli ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want Python2 instead of Python3?

Comment: no I need python3 for some cases I may need python2.

Comment: Did you try using `python3` (instead of `python`)?

Comment: `python3 -m install -u pip
/usr/bin/python3: No module named install`
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$

Comment: Um, did you remember to install pip/pip3?

Comment: no I did not installed them that I Am sure. I dont know what to do now

Comment: You cannot use pip commands until you install pip or pip3. Looking up how to install pip and/or pip3 on Ubuntu (not Windows) would be a good start.

Comment: ok as given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023599/usr-local-bin-python-no-module-named-pip `apt-get install python3-pip
` I installed pip in the mean time I did `sudo apt-get install awscli` I was able to connect to my aws instance.  I don't know if I should try proceeding to isntall awscli again from this new pip. I do a ` pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
` so how to reach to pip3

Comment: Well, seems like your original problem is solved: You can connect to AWS using Python. You will eventually need to migrate from Python2 to Python3. Whether or not you use the aws module from apt or from pip/pip3 is entirely a matter of your preference.